# How to programatically read the xx.exe.confg file of another application

Tags: c#, wpf, config

I am trying to read the app settings in the config file of another application (app.exe.config).

I have tried several things. Most recently I used this:

```
        System.Configuration.Configuration config =
          ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(FullPath() + ".config");

        // Get the AppSetins section.
        AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = config.AppSettings;

        // Display raw xml.
        Debug.WriteLine(appSettingSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml());
```

but the GetRawXml() returns nothing. Where am I going wrong? The FullPath() method returns the correct path, I have tested this.

M

Comment: Does the config use 'appSettings' or 'applicationSettings' elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config files are valid xml files so you can also try using `XElement.Load(filepath)` and process the xml tree as desired.

```
var appSettingsRawXml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(FullPath() + ".config")
    .Element("appSettings")
    .ToString();
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like that's what I'm going to have to do. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`GetRawXml` supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.getrawxml.aspx)

Comment: Ok, so how do I do it?